# Distributing keys to professors (Combinatorics)

Tags: combinatorics

I was wondering if you could possibly give me a shove in the right direction in solving this combinatorics problem. My main issue is that I struggle a bit with recognising what I am meant to do in longer, more text heavy questions. In this particular instance, I am struggling to see what theorem/formula/idea to proceed with trying. I would really appreciate a small nudge to the effect of "X tells you Y, what can you do with that?" with some cursory explaination of how you got to that. My end goal is to improve with this style of problem and, maybe, seeing how you guys think might prove useful.

I appreciate if this is not the normal style of request for this site and thank you in advance for those who do take the time to respond. Also, sorry for the poor quality title, I was rather unsure what to title this post. If anyone has a better idea, feel free to edit!

***Question text***

"A university department has $100$ professors. Water damage destroys all but
$90$ offices. The university now has to distribute keys to the professors such that no
matter which $90$ professors come to the university, they can assign the offices to
themselves such that everyone can open their office. In addition, it is strictly forbidden to share
or trade keys. Of course, each professor can get multiple keys and keys to an office can
be given to more than one professor. Show that the minimum number of keys to distribute to the professors is $990$"

Comment: Try first with a scaled down version.

Comment: Thank you true blue anil. Having reduced to 10 professors and 9 offices I got the following:

9 professors in a day need 9 keys each. So thats 81 keys. The remaining professor needs a set of 9 keys as well so we have 81+9 keys in total.

I am still struggling to see how this would give us 990 as the minimal number of keys for the original problem as, by the same logic, we would need (90*90)+(10*90)=9000 keys which is a whole lot more than expected.

Prehaps you can spot where ive gone wrong?

Comment: Your solution works, but as the problem says, you can do better.  Some of the professors only need $1$ key.  How many?  I have a solution that works for $990$ but not a proof that it is minimal.

Comment: A clarification is needed first. There are $100$ professors, but only $90$ offices. Then what is the meaning of "... distribute keys to the professors such that no matter which 90 professors come to the university, they can assign the offices to themselves such that **everyone can open their office.** " But surely $10$ offices have been destroyed, where are you to assign offices for those $10$ professors. ? ? ?

Comment: For clarification, I believe that the question is meant to be interpreted such that there are 100 professors seeking office space but there are only 90 offices. To deal with this, on any given day, 90 will come in to work and the other 10 will stay home. They all, however, need keys to get into any of the offices as it won't the same 90 professors coming in every day.

Comment: THank you for your reply, Ross. How did you arrive at your number of professors only needing a single key each? It may be possible to prove that your answer of 990 is minimal as required by seeing what happens if you take away one key so you only have 989 left

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, with your clarification, we shall have to go by the  scenario that out of the $90$ lucky persons whose ofiice is intact, if even one is missing , the "unlucky" person replacing her just has her own  useless key (which we can as well consider destroyed), and since any of the lucky $90$ may be the missing person, has to hold the keys to each of the $90$ offices.

Thus minimum number of keys needed $=10*90 +90 =990$

Comment: Maybe I was a little unclear in my clarification, I am sorry for that. I believe the point of the question is "how many keys do I have to get made to distribute between 100 people so that 90 out of 100 randomly selected employees can go and work in one of my 90 offices. " It seems to be a "hot desking but with offices" situation if you follow!

Comment: Thank you Anil, I think I follow you now! 
To begin, everyone had their own office and there was 100 keys.

Now that 10 have been destroyed, 90 people still have their own office and 10 people are officeless.

To accomodate those 10 people, we give them each of them a key to all of the offices. Then, if one of the people who did not lose their office is not in, one of our office-less professors is able to walk in there and work.

Thank you for your input. Now that I can follow the thread, it seems very clear!

Comment: Glad to be of help ! $\;\;$ :)